# I have to generate 10000 numbers which are the result of 12 random numbers subtracted by 0.5 and then added together

Tags: random, wolfram-mathematica, normal-distribution

I'm stuck here, and can't generate a do loop that repeats this operation 10k times and result in a list or array

```
{((RandomVariate[TruncatedDistribution[{0, 1}, NormalDistribution[]], 
 12])) - 0.5}
```

Comment: Hint: Study https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Total.html?q=Total Then  study https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? If so, I suspect you may be misinterpreting the instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Do](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Do.html) does things but it doesn't generate output. E.g.

```
Do[{1, 2, 3}, 2]
```

*- no output -*

Have it add to a list though...

```
alist = {};

Do[alist = Join[alist, {1, 2, 3}], 2]

alist
```

> {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3}

Comment: Does do do things?

Comment: Indeed it does.